# SPA OpenID Connect Security Issues

Tags: jwt, single-page-application, openid-connect

We have developed an SPA (Bootstrap / Angular) and separate Services layer (.Net) 
Our users will get very little access to anything on our site without first being redirected to a separate IdP. On signing in they'll then being redirected back with their ID Token in the SPA.

Once the user first registers we will go collate the information and associate it with their new account for retrieval each time they return.

Our intention is to then manage any state in the front end ( very little ) and keeping our back end totally stateless so ALL requests to the API will be validated by our back end ( JWT token signature and claims validation ), we'll get the users Identity ( ID token ) and serve the response if Authorized ( based on the 'Security Level' claim ).

We've CORS setup on the API to only accept requests from our SPA, so that should help somewhat but my worry is someone could steal the token somehow and use it to find out information about the user.

Is this really a possibility, am I missing some larger security vulnerabilities ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I only think that could occur if someone had executed a man-in-the-middle attack between the SPA client and the API/Resource service. Your SPA at some point gets an Auth bearer token, that can be passed on to the API/Resource service.

I found this video useful when planning our own OpenID Connect/OAuth2 implementation.

https://vimeo.com/113604459